# How do I perform a 'simplified experiment' with Nvidia's Performance Toolkit?

Tags: opengl, profiling, gpu, nvidia, performance-testing

I am trying to use Nvidia's performance toolkit to identify the performance bottleneck in an OpenGL application. Based on the user guide and the samples provided, I have arrived at this code:

```cpp
// ********************************************************
// Set up NVPMAPI
#define NVPM_INITGUID
#include "NvPmApi.Manager.h"
// Simple singleton implementation for grabbing the NvPmApi
static NvPmApiManager S_NVPMManager;
NvPmApiManager *GetNvPmApiManager() { return &S_NVPMManager; }
const NvPmApi* getNvPmApi() { return S_NVPMManager.Api(); }

void MyApp::profiledRender()
{
    NVPMRESULT nvResult;

    nvResult = GetNvPmApiManager()->Construct(L"C:\\Program Files\\PerfKit_4.1.0.14260\\bin\\win7_x64\\NvPmApi.Core.dll");
    if (nvResult != S_OK)
    {
        return; // This is an error condition
    }

    auto api = getNvPmApi();

    nvResult = api->Init();
    if ((nvResult) != NVPM_OK)
    {
        return; // This is an error condition
    }

    NVPMContext context;
    nvResult = api->CreateContextFromOGLContext((uint64_t)::wglGetCurrentContext(), &context);
    if (nvResult != NVPM_OK)
    {
        return; // This is an error condition
    }

    api->AddCounterByName(context, "GPU Bottleneck");

    NVPMUINT nCount(1);
    api->BeginExperiment(context, &nCount);
    for (NVPMUINT i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
        api->BeginPass(context, i);

        render();
        glFinish();

        api->EndPass(context, i);
    }
    api->EndExperiment(context);

    NVPMUINT64 bottleneckUnitId(42424242);
    NVPMUINT64 bottleneckCycles(42424242);
    api->GetCounterValueByName(context, "GPU Bottleneck", 0, &bottleneckUnitId, &bottleneckCycles);
    char name[256] = { 0 };
    NVPMUINT length = 0;
    api->GetCounterName(bottleneckUnitId, name, &length);
    NVPMUINT64 counterValue(42424242), counterCycles(42424242);
    api->GetCounterValue(context, bottleneckUnitId, 0, &counterValue, &counterCycles);

    std::cout << "--- NVIDIA Performance Kit GPU profile ---\n"
        "bottleneckUnitId: " << bottleneckUnitId 
        << ", bottleneckCycles: " << bottleneckCycles 
        << ", unit name: " << name
        << ", unit value: " << counterValue
        << ", unit cycles: " << counterCycles
        << std::endl;
}
```

However, the printed output shows that all of my integer values have been left unmodified:

```
--- NVIDIA Performance Kit GPU profile ---
bottleneckUnitId: 42424242, bottleneckCycles: 42424242, unit name: , unit value:
 42424242, unit cycles: 42424242
```

I am in a valid GL context when calling `profiledRender` and while the cast in `api->CreateContextFromOGLContext((uint64_t)::wglGetCurrentContext(), &context);` looks a tiny bit dodgy it does return an OK result (whereas passing `0` for the context will return a not-OK result and putting in a random number will cause an access violation).

This is built against Cinder 0.8.6 running in x64 on Windows 8.1. Open GL 4.4, GeForce GT 750M.

Answer (score 0):

Ok some more persistent analysis of the API return codes and further examination of the manual revealed the problems.

1. The render call needs to be wrapped in `api->BeginObject(context, 0);` and `api->EndObject(context, 0);`. That gives us a bottleneckUnitId.
2. It appears that the `length` pointer passed to `GetCounterName` both indicates the char array size as an input and is written to with the string length as output. This is kind of obvious on reflection but is a mistake copied from the user guide example. This gives us the name of the bottleneck.